# Do Mixpanel events update retrospectively?

Tags: javascript, analytics, mixpanel

Say John visits a website on Monday and the website sends Mixpanel a `landingVisit`event with a super-property of `1`.

Then John visits the website on Wednesday and the website sends Mixpanel a `landingVisit` event with a super-property of `2`

On Friday, I go to the Segmentation panel of Mixpanel.  Will I see a `landingVisit` event for John dated Monday with a super-property of `1` **AND** a `landingVisit` event dated Wednesday with a super-property of `2`?

Or will the events dated Monday and Wednesday both have a super-property of `2` (i.e. the super-property of the Monday event retrospectively updated)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Event data in Mixpanel is write once, read forever. This means there's no way your previous events will be altered by a subsequent event.

Comment: Thx I just confirmed this with Karl, a support engineer at Mixpanel.  He used almost the exact same words "write once, read forever".